# Can't connect to wired Internet with ubuntu 18.04 desktop.1 on workstation pro 15 but can connect use virtual box

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager, vmware

On booting,I got a failed info about Network Manager,after finishing creating a 
virtual machine:

I got:

```
    oneslide@ubuntu:~$ systemctl status NetworkManager-wait-online.service 
● NetworkManager-wait-online.service - Network Manager Wait Online
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager-wait-online.service; enab
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-01-24 11:39:18 PST; 2min 6
     Docs: man:nm-online(1)
 Main PID: 704 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 24 11:38:48 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Wait Online...
Jan 24 11:39:18 ubuntu systemd[1]: NetworkManager-wait-online.service: Main pro
Jan 24 11:39:18 ubuntu systemd[1]: NetworkManager-wait-online.service: Failed w
Jan 24 11:39:18 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start Network Manager Wait Online
```

I indeed know ubuntu 18.04 start up with DHCP default,but I successfully
create a VM with internet connecting on virtualBox using bridge connecting,so I test it on VMware 15 with bridge connecting Internet.

But it can't work!even when I follow official documentation to configure from System setting->network...

I don't know what network manager is,it overwrites many config files and conflict
with them,what can I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to delete this question about my stupid mistake!
and I finally successfully connect Internet,and reasons are there:

1.go to device manager of Windows to check attribute about NIC information,check Connectivity.
2.if your physical computer has several NICs,you must explicitly set a NIC bridge connected with virtual switch which connect to all VM.otherwise,It will choose a NIC with more bandwith.

In my situation,
there are two NIC:

- Intel Ethernet Connection I219-LM | not connected but more bandwidth
- Intel Ethernet I210-T1 GbE NIC  |connected with lower bandwidth

so do not set bridge to automatic in Virtual Network Editor,explicitly set one!